# trackpad disable buttons but keep cursor movements

Tags: mouse, touchpad

I only wan't my trackpad to move the cursor (no tap to click)

So far I have tried all these things: https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/disable-click-track-pad/15538/2

but as we can see (the true state of the trackpad) here:

```
--list-props 11
Device 'ImPS/2 Generic Wheel Mouse':
    Device Enabled (139):   1
    Coordinate Transformation Matrix (141): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
    Device Accel Profile (264): 0
    Device Accel Constant Deceleration (265):   1.000000
    Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (266):   1.000000
    Device Accel Velocity Scaling (267):    10.000000
    Device Product ID (259):    2, 5
    Device Node (260):  "/dev/input/event6"
    Evdev Axis Inversion (268): 0, 0
    Evdev Axes Swap (270):  0
    Axis Labels (271):  "Rel X" (149), "Rel Y" (150), "Rel Vert Wheel" (263)
    Button Labels (272):    "Button Left" (142), "Button Middle" (143), "Button Right" (144), "Button Wheel Up" (145), "Button Wheel Down" (146), "Button Horiz Wheel Left" (147), "Button Horiz Wheel Right" (148)
    Evdev Scrolling Distance (273): 1, 1, 1
    Evdev Middle Button Emulation (274):    1
    Evdev Middle Button Timeout (275):  50
    Evdev Third Button Emulation (276): 0
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Timeout (277): 1000
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Button (278):  3
    Evdev Third Button Emulation Threshold (279):   20
    Evdev Wheel Emulation (280):    0
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Axes (281):   0, 0, 4, 5
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Inertia (282):    10
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Timeout (283):    200
    Evdev Wheel Emulation Button (284): 4
    Evdev Drag Lock Buttons (285):  0
```

we have "Button Left" (142), "Button Middle" (143), "Button Right" (144)

I am asking here because I am nervous and don't want to mess up my trackpad.

Is this syntax correct to disable left, middle and right buttons?

```
xinput disable 11 142
xinput disable 11 143
xinput disable 11 144
```

## Update

I grew a pair, tried it and it doesn't work!

if anyone finds out please do tell

these trackpad features are dangerous! I keep flinging icons, selecting text, collapsing windows all by accident